# jQuery: How do I POST on CLICK?

Tags: php, jquery, post, click, onclick

I'm trying to figure out how I can pass data from `page-list.php` to `page.php` using jQuery .post() and .click().

Code in `<head>` of page-list.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.link').click(function () {
        $.post("page.php", {pageID: "1"} );
    }
});
</script>
```

Code in `<body>` of page-list.php:

```
<button class="btn link">LINK</button>
```

When I click LINK, nothing happens.

I'm also not sure how to call the posted data on page.php. Should I create a variable in PHP like this?

```
$pageID = ($_POST['pageID']);
```

And then call it in the body like this?

```
echo $pageID;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do is $.post() a variable to "page.php" and *then* redirecting to "page.php".

If that *is* what you are trying to do it just won't work. $_POST requests are independent of each other, i.e. using $.post, accessing $_POST['pageID'] will result in whatever value you sent but won't display anything because the browser was not sent to the new page with the variables; but redirecting and trying to access the same variable will result in "null".

It is that same reason that when you use a log in system and refresh the page right afterwards the browser confirms that you want to send the information again.

Using $_GET might be more of what you need. Another option would be to use and form to post the variables.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have done this before using forms, but thought I could do it with jQuery .post(). I have redone the code as follows: `<form action="page.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="pageID" value="1" /><input type="submit" name="start" value="Start" class="btn" /></form>`.

Comment: Sometimes simplicity is the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you are missing a couple of characters.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.link').click(function () {
        $.post("page.php", {pageID: "1"} );
    }); // missing end of statement.
});
</script>
```

Comment: That is a silly mistake. I've fixed it, but still nothing is happening. Thanks for catching that though!

Comment: How do you know nothing happens? Have you placed an `alert` call in the click function to see if it called?

Comment: I thought .post() is supposed to redirect me to page.php? I did put an alert in the click function and it is working. I'm just not sure why the .post() doesn't seem to be working (i.e. redirecting me to page.php).

Comment: Post doesn't redirect. It sends the data in the background via ajax while leaving the user on the current page.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I will be able to redirect the user by making .link an actual link. I'm still not sure though how to call the data passed on the new page. Would it be something like `$pageID = ($_POST['pageID']);` and `echo $pageID;`?

Comment: I don't know php. It would be however you get a form field on any other php page.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe someone else can help me with this part or I'll find it myself eventually. Letting me know .post() didn't redirect was very helpful!

Comment: The way I would call info from a PHP form is as follows: `if ($_POST['NAME']) {$pageID = ($_POST['pageID']);}` and then `echo $pageID`. I'm just not sure what NAME should be when I use .post() instead of a form submit button. When using a form, NAME is the name field of the submit button.

Comment: It is whatever you specified. pageID in this case.