# How to make a php variable $_POST upon clicking it?

Tags: php, html, variables, post

I'm trying to make `$suggestion[$ss_count]` become a clickable link that does a `$_POST` once it is clicked. I'm trying to achieve a query expansion sort of an effect. The word itself of course needs to be the information posted and it needs to be recognized as

```
if ($_POST['query'])
```

The code I use for this is:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['query'])

{
    $query = urlencode($_POST['query']);
    $s_count = 0;
    $ss_count = 0;
    $query = 'http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/'.$query.'?   key=135a6187-af83-4e85-85c1-1a28db11d5da';
    $xml = new SimpleXMLIterator(file_get_contents($query));
    foreach ($xml -> suggestion as $suggestion[$s_count])
    {
        $s_count++;
    }
    if ($s_count > 1)
    {
        echo ('<h4>Did you mean?</h4>');
        while ($ss_count <=$s_count)
        {
        echo ($suggestion[$ss_count].'<br>');
        $ss_count++;
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Why POST? Use GET instead

Comment: The rest of my code accepts only $_POST.

Comment: you might want to look into sending POST request using jQuery/AJAX. Something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115119/jquery-how-do-i-post-on-click

Comment: Have you tried $_REQUEST['query']?

Comment: if your code only accepts `$_POST`, maybe it's time to start changing your code

Comment: Can I use get to put the variables in to form field?